# Is extension methods follow open close principle

Tags: c#, extension-methods, open-closed-principle

My question is about extension method and open close principle:

1. Do creating extensions methods for classes follow open-close principle?
2. How do I test classes that use extension methods?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Do creating extensions methods for classes follow open-close principle?

Technically yes, as most formal definitions state that the open/closed principle is "Closed for modification, but open for extension". Since extensions methods are not modifying the original class, but only extending it, extension methods fits this definition.

> 2. How do I test classes that use extension methods?

Just like any other test:

Example extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToLowerAndTrim(this string source) => source.Trim().ToLower();
}
```

Test case using XUnit:

```
[Fact]
public void SampleTest()
{
    string input = " Hello World ";
    string expected = "hello world";

    string actual = input.ToLowerAndTrim();

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```